# Unable to create/draw on an X11 overlay window

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

I am trying to create a transparent window on top of all the other windows on which I can draw some stuff. I tried using the composite extension for Xlib and tried to create an X composite overlay window. But when I run the program nothing seems to happen. There doesn't seem to be an overlay window displayed and there is nothing being drawn on it.

If I replace the overlay window with a conventional window created using `XCreateSimpleWindow` then everything works as expected and a window shows up with the line being drawn on it. What am I doing wrong here? I'm new to working with Xorg. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h>

int main() {

    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (display == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't establish connection with X Server");
    }

    int screen_id = DefaultScreen(display);

    Window parent = XRootWindow(display, screen_id);
    int black_color = BlackPixel(display, screen_id);
    int white_color = WhitePixel(display, screen_id);

    Window overlay_window = XCompositeGetOverlayWindow(display, parent);
    XMapWindow(display, overlay_window);
    XFlush(display);

    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, overlay_window, 0, NULL);
    XSetForeground(display, gc, white_color);

    XEvent event;
    XSelectInput(display, overlay_window, ExposureMask);
    for(;;) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        switch(event.type) {
        case Expose:
            XDrawLine(display, overlay_window, gc, 0, 100, 200, 100);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Arch linux using openbox WM and the picom compositor. If that is relevant.

Comment: Have you tried to draw without waiting for expose events?

Comment: Oh yeah that seems to work. So there is no Expose or MapNotify events  when the overlay window is mapped? Also the line keeps flickering if the compositor (picom) is running. But when I kill it, the window seems to function as expected. I also tried drawing in response to mouse clicks, this also only seems to work when the compositor is off.